# c# \t and String.Replace not working for string format

Tags: arrays, string, loops, format

I am writing a program to list the 15 most recent results from a csv file. For some reason I cannot use a few of the string modifiers, while others work as I remember.
Its been a few years since I have tried to program something, but I feel that something else is going on here, in Visual Studio, it will not tab, but does work with other string modifiers, like \n for new line

This code works to pull in the data, and creates 3 strings, with nothing in between the values inside the string.
I understand I am basically just pulling the line apart and putting it back together, but String.Replace is not working either.

[Output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjnUH.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public void inputValues(string filePath)
{

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(doc))
    {   

        string output=null;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();

            var values = line.Split(',');

            for(int i = 0; i<=5;i++)
            {
                output += values[i] + "\t";
            }
            output += "\n";
            lblResults.Text = output;
        }       
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `lblResults`? A control? Maybe it just doesn't support tabs?